# Define Enumeration inside Main() gives compile Error ( c#)

Tags: c#, enumeration

Define Enumertion inside Main() gives compile error,Why it so ?  (If define it in 'class program, working fine)

```
   using System;

        class program
         {
            // If define here, it works fine.
            // public enum Days {Sunday,Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday,Saturday};
            static void Main()
              {
                public enum Days {Sunday,Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday,Saturday}
                Days today;
                today = Days.Saturday;

                Console.WriteLine("Today is {0}",today);
              }

        }
```

**Compile Error:**

```
d:\MyProgs>csc _19enum.cs
Microsoft (R) Visual C# 2010 Compiler version 4.0.30319.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

_19enum.cs(7,5): error CS1513: } expected
_19enum.cs(10,15): error CS1519: Invalid token '=' in class, struct, or
        interface member declaration
_19enum.cs(10,30): error CS1519: Invalid token ';' in class, struct, or
        interface member declaration
_19enum.cs(12,20): error CS1519: Invalid token '(' in class, struct, or
        interface member declaration
_19enum.cs(12,41): error CS1519: Invalid token ')' in class, struct, or
        interface member declaration
_19enum.cs(15,1): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file
        expected
```

Comment: I am newbie in C#, Down voters.. would you please consider this point,Please!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't define enums inside a method. Define them in the class, or preferably outside the class if you are going to use them elsewhere:

```
using System;

public enum Days {Sunday,Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday,Saturday}

class program
 {
    // here is fine too

    static void Main()
      {
        Days today;
        today = Days.Saturday;

        Console.WriteLine("Today is {0}",today);
      }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

An `enum` is at its heart a `const` declaration and cannot be declared in a method.

Check out the C# Specification at `Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0/VC#/Specifications/1033` for more information.

Comment: How to check that Specifications?, Sorry I am a newbie in C#

Comment: @Arun it is a word document entitled *CSharp Language Specification.docx*.

Comment: Hi OmegaMan, Yes I located that document.

Answer (score 1):

Well the answer to your question is, because [C# specs](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7029) say so.

> **9.6 Type declarations** [*(from C# specification document)*](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7029)
>
> A type-declaration is a class-declaration (§10.1), a
>   struct-declaration (§11.1), an interface-declaration (§13.1), **an
>   enum-declaration** (§14.1), or a delegate-declaration (§15.1).

So `enum` is a type, later if we see in the same section.

> A **type-declaration can occur as a top-level declaration** in a
>   compilation unit or as a member declaration within a namespace, class,
>   or struct.

A method is not a top-level declaration, only possible options are namespace, class and struct.

So you can't define an `enum` inside a method.